# How do I embed an inline attachment with Mailchimp?

Tags: email, inline, mailchimp

Mailchimp has no functionality for attaching files, however, I am trying to hack it by setting the multipart headers in plain text mode and then pasting the contents of the file beneath (with the proper headers set). Unfortunately, I can't quite get this to work.

I'm trying to send calendar invites.

It sets a plaintext header above my calendar header.

[Here's an example](http://pastebin.com/yHh1FVRa) of how the email comes through (personal details removed). Gmail isn't picking up the calendar invite- can anyone see why?

http://pastebin.com/yHh1FVRa

Comment: Just utilize the MailChimp API. Here's the docs: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com

Answer (score 1):

Correct, Mailchimp won't let you send e-mails. Please see more about the reasons here: https://blog.mailchimp.com/adding-file-attachments-to-mailchimp-email-campaigns/

As Mailchimp doesn't want you to send Attachments, I would not recommend to hack around this. I also imagine Mailchimp added some protection for this, in example stripping out parts of the message before sending it.

You should link up your content as described the blog post.

Answer (score -2):

MailChimp DOES allow you to enter a link to the file (and host the file on MailChimp).  That may accomplish what you want.  See [this KB article](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-send-attachments-with-mailchimp)

I am looking into sending a google calendar invite right now too .. I will post back once I am successful.

Comment: I can make a link to an INDIVIDUAL campaign.  The issue is with inserting the "folder archive" snipped I show above.  That is the MailChimp way to reference all the campaigns in a folder (hosted by MailChimp).  I just cannot find a way to get this javascript executed on a Google Site webpage.  (If you put the same information into a page on your own computer you can see the expected results.)